# Adding multiple Text Views Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add multiple Text Views on a new Activity based on the input from a previous one when the user presses the button. My problem is that it only adds ONE Text View which is the last input every time.

Main Activity Code:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReadActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text",text.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Text Views Activity:

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");

    LinearLayout ll=findViewById(R.id.read_activity);
    TextView tv= new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(text);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layoutParams.setMargins(30,30,30,0);
    ll.addView(tv);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Subject added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

read_activity is the activity I want to add the Text Views.

Comment: Why do you start the Activity again and again? Just add the TextView

Comment: Which activity? Both codes are inside inCreate(). Is this wrong?

Comment: If you want to add a TextView clicking in the Button, just add the TV in the setOnClickListener without starting a new Activity with an Intent

Comment: The button is in a different activity from the one that I want to add the TextViews, that's why I start a new Activity with Intent.

Comment: You only have code to add a single `TextView` here, so I am not sure why you think it should be adding multiple?

Comment: So what should I change in order to add multiple? That's actually my question.

Comment: @Christina can you tell exactly how much textview you want?

Comment: Well you'd run the code multiple times? So in a method and or loop?

Comment: For some reason it works if the input EditText and the dynamic Text Views are in the same activity. There isn't anyway to change activity and at the same time add the TextView to this second activity?